# How to slice a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array say

```
arr1 = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

I want to slice it and pick 2nd and 3rd column.

I have tried using slice but it did not work.

`var result = arr1.slice(1,3);`

but I dont get the desired output which should be

```
[[2,3],[6,7],[10,11]]
```

Is it because I am using Google spreadsheet to collect data?

Comment: I am extremely sorry I meant column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to map the sliced arrays.

```js
const
    array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]],
    customSlice = array => array.slice(1, 3),
    result = array.map(customSlice);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```